# JsRender if condition fails inside custom range tags

Tags: if-statement, jsrender

I am trying to add a selected class to my img tag inside a range tag.

```
 <ul class="cci-TweetContainer">
  {{range refTweets start=0 end=9}}
    <li data-userID="{{:userId}}">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" alt="User Avatar" data-userID="{{:userId}}">
          {{if refTweets == 0}}
            <img class="selected" src="{{:userAvatar}}" alt="User avatar icon" width="25" height="25" />
          {{else}}
            <img src="{{:userAvatar}}" alt="User avatar icon" width="25" height="25" />
          {{/if}}
      </a>
    </li>
   {{/range}} 
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is refTweets an array? If so then within the {{range}} the current data object will be the current item in the refTweets array. So testing for `refTweets == 0` seems not to make sense. You are in effect testing for the refTweets property on the current object - so `refTweet.refTweets == 0` - which will always be false.

You can pass in context like this:

`{{range refTweets ~selId=selectedId start=0 end=9}}
    <li data-userID="{{:userId}}">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" alt="User Avatar" data-userID="{{:userId}}">
          {{if userId === ~selId}}
             ...
          {{else}}
             ...
          {{/if}}
      </a>
    </li>
   {{/range}}`

(Assuming you have a selectedId property on the same object that has the refTweets property).

Comment: Thanks Boris, I agree with your solution but I got a easier solution working by querying #getIndex(#parent) == 0 in the if condition.

Answer (score -1):

Got the code working by adding #getIndex(#parent) which refers to refTweets property.

```
{{range refTweets start=0 end=9}}
        <li data-userID="{{:userId}}">
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" alt="User Avatar" data-userID="{{:userId}}">
              {{if #getIndex(#parent) == 0}}
                <img class="selected" src="{{:userAvatar}}" alt="User avatar icon" width="25" height="25" />
              {{else}}  
                <img src="{{:userAvatar}}" alt="User avatar icon" width="25" height="25" />
              {{/if}}  
          </a>
        </li>
{{/range}}
```

Comment: Actually getIndex() doesn't take a parameter, so passing in #parent is not doing anything. It would be equivalent to write {{if !#getIndex()}}.

Comment: In fact you can even just write {{if !#index}} - you are simply selecting the first item in the list. (It wasn't clear from your question that that is what you wanted...)

Comment: sorry about that, I'll try to be more specific next time. But thank you for taking the time to answer my question.